# SMS archive solutions

Tags: text, sms, message, archive

Does anyone know if there are any SMS archive solution out there?  The idea is to archive your sms message from your phone to a central location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not as automatic as you wish for, but you can read out all the sms messages with [AT](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27005.htm) [commands](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm). I regularly do to back up my mobile phone. Running

```
at+cscs="UTF-8"
at+cgmi;+cgmr
at+cpms="SM","SM"; +cmgl=4
at+cpms="ME","ME"; +cmgl=4
```

will dump (possibly in PDU mode) all messages stored on sim and in phone memory. While you are at it, having a backup of the phonebook and list of calls dialled/missed/received is nice to have as well:

```
at+cpbs="SM"; +cpbr=1,200
at+cpbs="ME"; +cpbr=1,2500
at+cpbs="DC"; +cpbr=1,30
at+cpbs="MC"; +cpbr=1,30
at+cpbs="RC"; +cpbr=1,30
```

Capture the output from the terminal program to a text file, and this file you can distribute in whatever way you like.

Update: The maximum range numbers in the above commands are for my sim card and my phone, yours will probably be a bit different. You can query the range with the by issuing the `test operation` of AT+CPBR (AT commands have three basic operations, `set/execute` (e.g. AT+CPBS="ME"), `read` (e.g. AT+CPBS?) and `test` (e.g. AT+CPBS=?), see [V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) for more details):

```
at+cpbs="SM"; +cpbr=?
at+cpbs="ME"; +cpbr=?
at+cpbs="DC"; +cpbr=?
at+cpbs="MC"; +cpbr=?
at+cpbs="RC"; +cpbr=?
```

Answer (score 0):

If its just one phone then there are usb keys / software packages that can read and archive data from sim cards

e.g. http://www.iwantoneofthose.com/usb-sim-card-reader/index.html

If its many phones; you probably need to speak to the phone company as they can likely provide a solution.